# What is causing brown spots on my Alocasia Black Velvet?

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, tropical

About two months ago I bought an Alocasia black velvet for on my desk. My office has a large window and the plant stand at a distance of around 3 meters from the window, so not in direct sunlight. I water it twice a week, letting surplus water drain from the bottom. Recently the plant's leaves are showing brown spots, shown in the picture. I've tried watering the plant less but then the leaves tend to hang a lot lower.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: You've got little white flecks over the leaf. Not sure it's relevant to the necrotic area. Can you take pictures of the underside looking for insects, and use a macro lens?

Comment: I wouldn't be concerned if it's just one little spot. It could be because of moving or other types of stress on the plant. Are you fertilizing your plant? Are you setting water aside for Chlorine to evaporate before watering?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the insect pests like spider mites have gotten to it. They hide under the leaves and sometimes fungus can develop brown spots on plant leaves. You can remove the infected part of the leaves and increase air circulation to get rid of the fungal diseases. Keeping it dry and maybe adding some chemicals to keep the bugs away can help